# Need help for integrating sap adapter with wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I working on WSO2 ESB profile for sap adapter. I followed the step for configuring sap adapter with WSO2 as mentioned in manual. But yet after starting the server, I am not able to create BapiSender proxy service in management console. It is marked default with the error

SAPTransportListener Unable to configure the service BAPISender for the BAPI transport: Service doesn't have configuration information for transport bapi. This service is being marked as faulty and will not be available over the BAPI transport.
WARN - SAPTransportListener Disabling the bapi transport for the service BAPISender, because it is not configured properly for the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your proxy service? Below you'll find a working example proxy.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SAPProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml" description="BAPIPayload">
            <format>
               <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <soap:Body>
                     <bapirfc xmlns="" name="Z_CONVERT_IBAN_2_BANK_ACCOUNT">
                        <import>
                           <field name="I_IBAN">123456789</field>
                        </import>
                     </bapirfc>
                  </soap:Body>
               </soap:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint name="sap-endpoint">
               <address uri="bapi:/yourconf"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="step" value="--- AFTER SEND TO SAP 2 --"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="step" value="--- RESULT FROM SAP --"/>
         </log>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="step" value="--- FAULT --"/>
         </log>
         <drop/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Above is the Bapi I am using for test run

Comment: <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="BAPISender"
       transports="bapi"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint name="sap_bapi_endpoint">
                    <address uri="bapi:/SAPSYS"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>

Comment: Not sure if it's a c&p problem but there's a ";" after the namespace that's not needed. Furthermore you've configured the proxy to receive bapi calls. So the question is are you trying to send data to sap or want to receive data from sap or another system (into esb) that sends the data in bapi format? If you want to receive you must also enable transportReceiver name="bapi" in axis2.xml.